# Database does not updated after publish

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first, azure-mobile-services

We have many mobile services which work by pair, one for the Dev and one for the production. These mobile servies use a SQL Azure Database as repository.

In summary :

**Production-Service ----> Production-Database on the Production-Server**

**Dev-Service ----> Dev-Database on the Dev-Server.**

Actually we can publish on the dev service. We've got a blue smiley (that appears after a few seconds) and modification on database (add column) are performed.

But, when we publish on the prod service. We’ve got also a blue smiley (which appears immediately) BUT the modification on database (add column) doesn’t appears !

After investigation, the only thing change between the two environments, since the last success publishing, is the auditing activation on the prod server. Since this audit was disabled.

More deep, when we read the migration History table, we can see a line for the dev but not on prod.

On the dev-database :

```
SELECT [MigrationId]
      ,[ContextKey]
      ,[Model]
      ,[ProductVersion]
FROM [dev-server-name].[dev-database-name].[__MigrationHistory]
```

Result  => 201509240834243_AutomaticMigration   last migration : today

On the prod-database :

```
SELECT [MigrationId]
      ,[ContextKey]
      ,[Model]
      ,[ProductVersion]
FROM [prod-server-name].[prod-database-name].[__MigrationHistory]
```

Result  => 201506291336002_AutomaticMigration   last migration : 2015/06/29

For information, we have this problem for all our production services. Conversely, our development services work perfectly.

The only common point between all of our production services is the server on which their database is hosted. But each service has its own database.

**In summary, we can no longer publish any changes on our databases in production.**

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Try following this guide: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application .  Especially the part on: "Execute Code First Migrations".

Answer (score 0):

Try this tutorial, which explains how to enable migrations for Mobile Services. It sounds like you have a more complex environment, but perhaps there's a missing configuration step somewhere: [How to make data model changes to a .NET backend mobile service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-code-first-migrations/).